# I need to add a some more rules on textarea tag from low-security-policy in ashai to antisamy project

Tags: sakai

Actually i have a html code with empty textarea tag now i need to send this one to anti samy project but it will convert empty textarea tag to self closing textarea tag

```
 String html="<textarea></textarea> some data here <textarea></textarea>";
```

when i send the above code to anti samy it will give a following output like:

```
String html="<textarea/>some data here <textarea/>";
```

but this is  not correct syntax in html so i think that i need to write the rules in "low-security-policy" in ashai for antisamy project.

so can any one help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At finally I found solution for this one

just remove textarea tag from allowed-empty tags in policy files then it will be working fine.